# Why is this not a constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, unions, constexpr

```
#include <iostream>

union gc_bits {
    size_t value;
    struct {
        size_t arena : 2;
    } bits;

    constexpr gc_bits(size_t value_) : value(value_) {
    }
};

static constexpr size_t get_max_arenas() {
    return gc_bits(~0ULL).bits.arena;
}

size_t current_colour[get_max_arenas()]; // error

int main() {
    std::cout << get_max_arenas() << std::endl;
}
```

The array declaration errors out because get_max_arenas is not a constexpr. I'm not clear on why this should be so.

Comment: By the way, you write to `value` and then read from `bits` in the union. Isn't that undefined behaviour in C++?

Comment: I don't know, you're allowed to read from the common prefixes in unions, and since both value and bits start with a size_t I think it should be allowed.

Comment: By the way 2: The standard doesn't say if the two bits are from the left or right end of the size_t. Limits portability. I would try with a shift and mask.

Comment: @DrPizza: there's a provision for reading from either of two `struct`s embedded in a `union`, when those `struct`s are standard-layout and share a common initial sequence of members, but only one of your members is a `struct` (and the provision for two `struct`s explicitly requires both to be bit fields of the same width, or neither to be a bit field).

Comment: @BoPersson: that would matter if it were all of `arena`'s bits being set, then `value` being read, but here all bits in `value` are set and given `arena` overlaps it can only be `3` (which may or may not have needed shifting to extract), if it all weren't undefined behaviour for other reasons.

Comment: @TonyD - If we *know* that the result is 3, we could skip all of this. :-) I assumed that DrPizza would use the bits elsewhere too.

Comment: Type-punning using unions is [not undefined in C but is in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11996970). Once you invoke UB all bets are off, so I dunno if the question still holds.

Comment: @BoPersson: the client code `gc_bits(~0ULL).bits.arena;` almost (but for undefined behaviour) serves to get the maximum value for `arena` without knowing the bit-field width: couldn't replace that with a hard-coded `3` without introducing an extra point of maintenance.

Comment: @TonyD: Exactly; I don't want to have to make reference to the bitfield width in more than one place (because I want to ensure that the different values are always in sync), but I fear I may have to. I'm struggling to see why the C++ spec makes unions and bit fields quite so limited, especially when C11 makes them somewhat more capable.

Comment: @DrPizza: there are ways to do this without aliasing - e.g. [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84d88224504bdfc5)

Comment: @TonyD: Hmm, that seems to work, though I'm not tremendously clean on having a second (bogus) constructor. Do you see any clean way to do this initializing multiple fields, without having to put them all in that bogus constructor? This is one of the things that would be nice with the punning; one-shot initialization of the whole bitfield.

Comment: @DrPizza: you can use `memcpy()` from any all-bits-set memory - the compiler's required to re-read the bit fields from memory afterwards - and probably `memset()`, which would be cleaner, though I haven't seen that discussed explicitly in the context of aliasing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Slightly rephrasing your program:

```
static constexpr auto gma = get_max_arenas();

size_t current_colour[gma]; // error
```

gives the Clang error:

> read of member 'bits' of union with active member 'value' is not
>   allowed in a constant expression

The reason you get this error is that the constructor sets the `value`, and then you try to read `bits`. This is not allowed, as commented by @gurka.

[**Standard**](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4527.pdf) quote:

> **[expr.const]**
>
> 2 A conditional-expression e is a core constant expression **unless** the
>   evaluation of e, following the rules of the abstract machine (1.9),
>   would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> (2.8) — an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) or modification (5.18,
>   5.2.6, 5.3.2) that is applied to a glvalue that refers to **a non-active member of a union** or a subobject thereof;

Comment: @DrPizza no it's not arbitrary: at runtime, it's [undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11373203/819272) to access a non-active union member, with no diagnostic required, whereas at compile-time, you get the extra service of a compiler error.

Comment: If you believe it is not arbitrary then please explain the rationale for not allowing type punning of types with trivial constructors, and in your answer please make sure to include an explanation of why C11 is wrong to permit this very thing.

Comment: @DrPizza I am not aware of the rationale for having that particular part in the Standard, so you might be right it's somewhat arbitrary, but given that it is undefined behavior at runtime, it's actually good to get an error at compile-time when used in a `constexpr` context.

Comment: @DrPizza In general, C++ is stricter than C to label certain language constructs as undefined behavior. This can help compilers make better optimizations. It's a tradeoff, because sometimes it also disallows code that on most machines would generate reasonable code.

Comment: Sure, I can see that, but I'd rather have C11-style type punning than compile-time enforcement of runtime-undefined behaviour.

Comment: @DrPizza: *"rather...type punning than compile-time enforcement of runtime-undefined behaviour"* - as TemplateRex said, the choice is between extra optimisations and defined behaviour accessing non-active members.  E.g. `void f(int a, int b) { if (a) my_union.my_float = 0.3; else my_union.my_int = 27; ...la-de-dah...; if (b) std::cout << my_union.my_float; }` in C++ the compiler can assume `b` will be non-zero whenever `a` is (otherwise it's a programmer error), and reuse a floating-point register storing 0.3 when calling `cout`.  Faster than forcing treatment as `volatile`/store+read of RAM.

Comment: If C can maintain decent performance without this kind of optimization then I'm quite sure C++ can too.