# Common-initial-sequence: with is it UB (undefined behaviour)

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, unions

The C++ standard says that accessing a non-active union member is UB.

But it states an exception from this rule for structs with a common-initial-sequence.

The following is such an example:

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
    T e0;
    T e1;
    T e2;
};
template<typename T>
struct B {
    T e0;
    T e1;
    T e2;
};
template<typename T>
union AB {
    A<T> a;
    B<T> b;
};

template<typename T>
constexpr char test() {
    AB<T> ab;
    ab.a.e0 = 1; 
    return ab.b.e0;
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto t1 = test<char>();    
}
```

UB is not allowed in constexpr-contexts, but the call to `test()` in `main()` results in an error at least for gcc. Why is this UB, although the C++ standard states the exception for this?

The error (g++) is:

In function 'int main()':
bm62.cc:107:35:   in 'constexpr' expansion of 'test()'
bm62.cc:107:36: error: accessing 'AB::b' member instead of initialized 'AB::a' member in constant expression
107 |     constexpr auto t1 = test();

Comment: I think the compiler doesn't know when evaulating the `constexpr` that the 2 classes initial sequence are the same

Comment: The lack of UB is not what is causing the error. You can't have a `constexpr` that refers to a non-active member of a union. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32624191/10871073). (Possible duplicate?) It's now in #5.10 of [expr.const](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const)

Comment: please include the compiler error in the question, I get a couple of errors, but none is related to accessing non active member afaict https://godbolt.org/z/arbnxdscP

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Changing OP's code to use `AB<T> ab = {{1,2,3}};` (and removing the assignment line) shows that the post I linked does, in fact, answer the question. I'm closing as a dupe - feel free to comment (or revert) if you disagree. [Modified Godbolt Sample](https://godbolt.org/z/a3nEGs9qq)

Comment: See error above (edit): it is clear the misuse of the inactive member

Comment: The standard says that it is ok to read the non-active member if the structs inside the union have a common-initial sequence, which is true for the above.

Comment: The Standard says it's OK to read the inactive member in such cases (i.e. at **run-time**) ... but the Standard also says that doing so is not valid in a `constexpr`.

Comment: The 'exception' [clause I linked](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.10) in my first comment: *an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion that is applied to a glvalue that refers to a non-active member of a union*. Now, the assignment operator is a clear case of lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.

Comment: But in https://eel.is/c++draft/class.union#general Note-1 explicitly defines such an exception.

Comment: No. You can't just "pick and choose" the parts of the Standard that you like. Your case is not UB but it is also **explicitly not allowed** in a `constexpr`.